# Database gets connected via DB client but not via Datasource explorer in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, db2, sqldatasource

I am experiencing an weird issue. 
we have a DB2 database that gets connected using DB client like Db-visualizer etc but it does not get connected when tried using datasource explorer in eclipse.

Doing so , I get an error stating : Error opening socket to server 
Error Code : -4499
SQL State :

As anyone faced this error or has any solution to this ?

Comment: Looks like you're providing an incorrect server IP address/hostname and/or DB2 port in Eclipse.

Comment: Everything is correct. Whole team is facing the issue. As i said, only DbVisualizer seems to work here. Strange :-(